# Groovy primitive double arithmetic

Tags: groovy, primitive-types

This yields 127

```
double middle = 255 / 2
```

While this yields 127.5

```
Double middle = 255 / 2
```

Meanwhile this yields 127.5 as well

```
double middle = (255 / 2) as double
```

I know that Groovy operates with BigDecimal per default, but to me this is a Huuge bug! How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with `BigDecimals`, but rather with the type coercion from primitive integer to the primitive double. This problem is caused by the Groovy compiler and the (most probably) incorrect bytecode it produces. Take a look at the following bytecode representation of the first case. The following Groovy code:

```
void ex1() {
    double x = 255 / 2
    println x
}
```

gets compiled to a bytecode that can be represented as:

```
public void ex1() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    double x = 0.0D;
    if (BytecodeInterface8.isOrigInt() && BytecodeInterface8.isOrigD() && !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()) {
        int var5 = 255 / 2;
        x = (double)var5;
    } else {
        Object var4 = var1[5].call(255, 2);
        x = DefaultTypeTransformation.doubleUnbox(var4);
    }

    var1[6].callCurrent(this, x);
}
```

It shows that in this case, it is not possible to get `127.5` as a result, because the result of `255 / 2` expression is stored in the variable of type `int`. It feels like this is an example of inconsistent behavior because here is what the bytecode of the method that uses `Double` looks like:

```
public void ex2() {
    CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
    Double x = null;
    if (BytecodeInterface8.isOrigInt() && !__$stMC && !BytecodeInterface8.disabledStandardMetaClass()) {
        Object var4 = var1[8].call(255, 2);
        x = (Double)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var4, Double.class);
    } else {
        Object var3 = var1[7].call(255, 2);
        x = (Double)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var3, Double.class);
    }

    var1[9].callCurrent(this, x);
}
```

The main problem with this use case is that adding `@TypeChecked` does not prevent you from making this mistake - compilation passes and the incorrect result is returned. However, when we add `@TypeChecked` annotation to the method that uses `Double` the compilation error is thrown. Adding `@CompileStatic` solves the problem.

I've run some tests and I can confirm that this problem exists in the recent **2.5.6**, as well as **3.0.0-alpha-4** versions. [I've created a bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9094) in the Groovy JIRA project. Thanks for finding and reporting the problem!

### UPDATE: Java does the same

It seems like this is not a Groovy bug - this is how Java does things as well. In Java, you can store a result of a division of two ints in the double variable, but you will get nothing else than an integer cast to the double. With {{Double}} type things are different in terms of the syntax but pretty similar in terms of the bytecode. With {{Double}} you need to explicitly cast at least one part of the equation to the {{double}} type, which results in the bytecode that casts both integers to the {{double}}. Consider the following example in Java:

```java
final class IntDivEx {

    static double div(int a, int b) {
        return a / b;
    }

    static Double div2(int a, int b) {
        return a / (double) b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(div(255,2));
        System.out.println(div2(255,2));
    }
}
```

When you run it you get:

```
127.0
127.5
```

Now, if you take a look at the bytecode it creates, you will see something like this:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

final class IntDivEx {
    IntDivEx() {
    }

    static double div(int a, int b) {
        return (double)(a / b);
    }

    static Double div2(int a, int b) {
        return (double)a / (double)b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(div(255, 2));
        System.out.println(div2(255, 2));
    }
}
```

The only difference (in terms of the syntax) between Groovy and Java is that Groovy allows you to implicitly cast an integer to `Double`, and that is why

```
Double x = 255 / 2
```

is the correct statement in Groovy, while Java, in this case, fails during the compilation with the following error:

```
Error:(10, 18) java: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.Double
```

That is why in Java you need to use casting when you assign from integer to `Double`.